# The best way of removing files from disk

Tags: python-2.7

To remove multiple files from disk, Which one of the following ways in the correct and efficient one:

```
try:
    os.remove(file1)
    os.remove(file2)
except OSError or IOError:
    pass
```

or

```
try:
    os.remove(file1)
except OSError or IOError:
    pass

try:
    os.remove(file2)
except OSError or IOError:
    pass
```

Comment: This would likely depend if all the files should be deleted, or if deletion should stop as soon as there's an error with any file. I don't think this can be definitely answered without more context.

Comment: @Carcigenicate so the second one seems more saver!

Comment: Well, with the first, if the first remove causes an error, the second remove won't happen since control will be transfered to the except. The second though would be neater if you used a function to wrap the common `try...except` bit, so you aren't repeating the same code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh! good point! Thanks alot